# Exclude Non-Working Hours Using NetworkDays.Intl As A Formula In Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using Excel 2019.

I get data weekly/monthly that contains anywhere from thousands to tens of thousands of rows.

My VBA code sorts this data by taking only what is needed.

I want to exclude non-working hours from two dates.

I came upon a formula, that works when applied into a cell with variables but I would like to include it in my VBA code.

The formula:

```
=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],""0000000"")-1)*(upper-lower)+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],""0000000""),MEDIAN(MOD([@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],1),upper,lower),upper)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],[@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],""0000000"")*MOD([@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],1),upper,lower)"
```

My target is that there are no weekends (hence using NetworkDays.Intl to custom set all as work days using "0000000"), and only set working hours (from 0800 to 2300) (8:00AM to 11:00PM), and any time after 11:01PM until 7:59AM is to be excluded from the total.

My VBA code for the above formula:

```vb
Sub RAWDATA_SORT()
    
    Dim Main As Worksheet, Processed As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, col As Long, k As Integer
    Dim colName As String, maincolName As String
    Dim i As Range
    Dim Headers As Range, SearchHeaders As Range
    Dim upper As Date, lower As Date, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Main = ActiveSheet
    Main.Name = "RAW DATA"
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("RAW DATA")).Name = "Processed Data"
    Set Processed = Sheets("Processed Data")
    Main.Activate
    Main.ShowAllData
    Set Headers = Main.Range("1:1")
    LastRow = 0
    lower = Format(TimeValue("08:00 AM"), "hh:mm AMPM")
    upper = Format(TimeValue("11:00 PM"), "hh:mm AMPM")
    Debug.Print (lower)
    Debug.Print (upper)
    
    ' More Code Here
    
    With Processed
    Processed.Activate
    Processed.AutoFilterMode = False
    Processed.ShowAllData
    
    ' More Code Here

    LastRow = Main.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    k = 2
    For Each i In Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
        StartDate = Range("N" & k).Value
        EndDate = Range("R" & k).Value
        Debug.Print (StartDate)
        Debug.Print (EndDate)
        Range("U" & k).Value = DateDiff("s", Range("N" & k).Value, Range("R" & k).Value)
        Range("V" & k).Value = "=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([" & StartDate & "],[" & EndDate & "],""0000000"")-1)*([" & upper & "]- [" & lower & "])" _
                                    & "+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([" & EndDate & "],[" & EndDate & "],""0000000""),MEDIAN(MOD([" & EndDate & "],1),[" & upper & "],[" & lower & "]),[" & upper & "])" _
                                    & "-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([" & StartDate & "],[" & StartDate & "],""0000000"")*MOD([" & StartDate & "],1),[" & upper & "],[" & lower & "])"
        k = k + 1
    Next i
    Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "General"
End With

    ' Proceeding to End
```

This is what the macro recorder gives:

```vb
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],""0000000"")-1)*(upper-lower)" & Chr(10) & "+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],""0000000""),MEDIAN(MOD([@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]],1),upper,lower),upper)" & Chr(10) & "-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],[@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],""0000000"")*MOD([@[DC_CREATION_DATE]],1),upper,lower)"
```

What I tried:

- Replacing Range("V" & k).Value with: Formula, FormulaR1C1, Formula2, Formula2R1C1
- Replacing Range with Cells
- Using `Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl` but I'm not experienced enough to translate the whole formula to code.

The result is nothing. It doesn't give any errors, but Column "V" is empty.

Alternatively, is there a better solution for excluding workhours without using NetworkDays.Intl (because there are no weekends)?

After commenting out "On Error Resume Next",

> Run-time error: 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error

on the line where my formula is placed.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` will silently ignore any errors, so start by commenting that out.

Comment: You're correct, again an oversight on my part, I've commented it out in my original code to see if any errors are returned and yes it did return an error 1004, Application undefined/object undefined error on where I've put the formula.

Comment: In what form is your time? Is the time including the date? Or is it just a form of time? There is insufficient information about the data.

Comment: I've reviewed your code, and there are a lot of confusing stuff. If you describe the actual contents with images, it will be easy to compare the contents you intend to use with the code and find the problems that arise.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Time format was DATE+TIME (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss) and yes I agree there will be visible confusion for this but the matter has been resolved by EEM to whom I'll award the bounty. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the posted Formula accurately returns the working hours between the `DC_CREATION_DATE` and the `ACTUAL_END_DATE`, the problem seems to be about how to enter an Excel formula using VBA.

**Op’s Formula:**

```
= ( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], "0000000" ) -1 ) * ( Upper - Lower )
 + IF( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], "0000000" ),
 MEDIAN( MOD( [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], 1 ), Upper, Lower ), Upper )
 - MEDIAN( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], "0000000" )
 * MOD( [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], 1 ), Upper, Lower )
```

The formula above seems to be obtained from an Excel Table (i.e. `ListObject`) as indicated by these parameters: `[@[DC_CREATION_DATE]]` and `[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]]`, while `Upper` and `Lower` seems to corresponds to `Defined Names`

The same formula using standard cells as parameters would be something like this:

```
= ( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( B7, C7, "0000000" ) -1 ) * ( Upper - Lower )
 + IF( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( C7, C7, "0000000" ),
 MEDIAN( MOD( C7, 1 ), Upper, Lower ), Upper )
 - MEDIAN( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( B7, B7, "0000000" )
 * MOD( B7, 1 ), Upper, Lower )
```

*Note that the parameters: `[@[DC_CREATION_DATE]]` and `[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]]` are replaced by the cells `B7` and `C7` respectively*

And that’s the problem with the Op’s code:

- *it’s not replacing the entire parameters*

  - Replacing only `@[DC_CREATION_DATE]` instead of `[@[DC_CREATION_DATE]]`
  - Replacing only `@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]` instead of `[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]]`
- Additionally it’s also wrapping Upper and Lower with `[` and `]`

[image]

**Processing Excel Formulas with VBA:**

I would suggest to add a validation of the `DC_CREATION_DATE` and `ACTUAL_END_DATE` at the beginning of the formula as follows:

```
= IF( [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]] < [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], 0,
 ( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], "0000000" ) -1 ) * ( Upper - Lower )
 + IF( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], "0000000" ),
 MEDIAN( MOD( [@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]], 1 ), Upper, Lower ), Upper )
 - MEDIAN( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], "0000000" )
 * MOD( [@[DC_CREATION_DATE]], 1 ), Upper, Lower ) )
```

I propose the following method to process excel formulas using VBA:

1. Substitute the parameters in the formula by key words that will be replaced by the `R1C1` reference of the actual values when running the procedure:

…

```
= IF( #END < #INI, 0," & vbLf & _
 ( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #INI, #END, "0000000" ) -1 ) * ( #UPR - #LWR )" & vbLf & _
 + IF( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #END, #END, "0000000" )," & vbLf & _
 MEDIAN( MOD( #END, 1 ), #UPR, #LWR ), #UPR )" & vbLf & _
 - MEDIAN( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #INI, #INI, "0000000" )" & vbLf & _
 * MOD( #INI, 1 ), #UPR, #LWR ) )"
```

Where:
`#INI` = `[@[DC_CREATION_DATE]]`
`#END` = `[@[ACTUAL_END_DATE]]`
`#LWR` = `Lower`
`#UPR` = `Upper`

```
By using the R1C1 reference of the cells we can update the formulas for the entire range at once instead of looping over each cell.
```

2. Define a constant to hold the formula template:

…

```
Const kFmlHours As String = "= IF( #END < #INI, 0," & vbLf & _
    " ( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #INI, #END, ""0000000"" ) -1 ) * ( #UPR - #LWR )" & vbLf & _
    " + IF( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #END, #END, ""0000000"" )," & vbLf & _
    " MEDIAN( MOD( #END, 1 ), #UPR, #LWR ), #UPR )" & vbLf & _
    " - MEDIAN( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #INI, #INI, ""0000000"" )" & vbLf & _
    " * MOD( #INI, 1 ), #UPR, #LWR ) )"
```

3. Define variables for the parameters as required:

…

```
Dim sFmlHours As String
Dim TimeLwr As Double, TimeUpr As Double
Dim sDateIni As String, sDateEnd As String
```

4. Replace the key words in the formula template with the corresponding values or the R1C1 reference:

…

```
        With .Range("V2")
            sDateIni = Range("N2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sDateEnd = Range("R2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sFmlHours = kFmlHours
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#INI", sDateIni)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#END", sDateEnd)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#LWR", TimeLwr)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#UPR", TimeUpr)
        End With
```

5. Enter the formula for the entire range, *(you can also replace the formulas with the resulting value)*:

…

```
        With .Range("V2:V" & lRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
            .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
        End With
```

**Procedure:**

This procedure only includes the calculation of the working hours:

```
Sub Formula_Working_Hours()
   
Const kFmlHours As String = "= IF( #END < #INI, 0," & vbLf & _
    " ( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #INI, #END, ""0000000"" ) -1 ) * ( #UPR - #LWR )" & vbLf & _
    " + IF( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #END, #END, ""0000000"" )," & vbLf & _
    " MEDIAN( MOD( #END, 1 ), #UPR, #LWR ), #UPR )" & vbLf & _
    " - MEDIAN( NETWORKDAYS.INTL( #INI, #INI, ""0000000"" )" & vbLf & _
    " * MOD( #INI, 1 ), #UPR, #LWR ) )"

Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsPrcs As Worksheet
Dim sFmlHours As String
Dim TimeLwr As Double, TimeUpr As Double
Dim sDateIni As String, sDateEnd As String
Dim lRow As Long
    
    Rem Set Lower & Upper Time
    TimeLwr = TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
    TimeUpr = TimeSerial(23, 0, 0)
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsMain = .Sheets("RAW DATA")
        Set wsPrcs = .Sheets("Processed Data")
    End With
    
    lRow = wsMain.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    
    With wsPrcs
                
        .Activate
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
            
        Rem Set Formula
        With .Range("V2")
            sDateIni = Range("N2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sDateEnd = Range("R2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sFmlHours = kFmlHours
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#INI", sDateIni)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#END", sDateEnd)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#LWR", TimeLwr)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#UPR", TimeUpr)
        End With
        
        Rem Enter Formula
        With .Range("V2:V" & lRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
            .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
        End With
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Your answer was very enlightening and detailed. It worked flawlessly as well as provided me with the much needed information and detail on how to work with formulas and references.

Comment: Glad it assist you in your VBA experience.

Answer (score 1):

There's a potential flaw here:

```vb
For Each i In Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        StartDate = Range("N" & k).Value
        EndDate = Range("R" & k).Value
        Debug.Print (StartDate)
        Debug.Print (EndDate)
        Range("U" & k).Value = DateDiff("s", Range("N" & k).Value, Range("R" & k).Value)
        Range("V" & k).Value = "=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([" & StartDate & "],[" & EndDate & "],""0000000"")-1)*([" & upper & "]- [" & lower & "])" _
                                    & "+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([" & EndDate & "],[" & EndDate & "],""0000000""),MEDIAN(MOD([" & EndDate & "],1),[" & upper & "],[" & lower & "]),[" & upper & "])" _
                                    & "-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([" & StartDate & "],[" & StartDate & "],""0000000"")*MOD([" & StartDate & "],1),[" & upper & "],[" & lower & "])"
        k = k + 1
Next i
```

You're looping over visible cells in Col N, so I'm assuming there's some filter applied here, and some rows are hidden.

If the very first row (#2) is hidden then you'll start with i=N3 but your `k` value will still be 2, so you're reading from/writing to a different row from the one you want.

Within the loop, `i.EntireRow` will give you each visible row, so you can work with (eg)

```vb
Dim rw As Range
'....
For Each i In Range("N2:N" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rw = i.EntireRow
    StartDate = rw.Columns("N").Value 'or just i.Value...
    EndDate = rw.Columns("R").Value
    'etc etc
```

Comment: The copied data to the new sheet "Processed Sheet" doesn't contain any filters, hence an oversight from my end and I've modified my code to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but take a look.

```
Sub RAWDATA_SORT()
    
    Dim Main As Worksheet, Processed As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, col As Long, k As Integer
    Dim colName As String, maincolName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Headers As Range, SearchHeaders As Range
    Dim upper As Date, lower As Date, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    
    Dim vR(), vTime()
    
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set Main = Sheets("RAW DATA")
    'Main.Name = "RAW DATA"
    'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("RAW DATA")).Name = "Processed Data"
    Set Processed = Sheets("Processed Data")
    'Main.Activate
    If Main.FilterMode Then
        Main.ShowAllData
    End If
    Set Headers = Main.Range("1:1")
    LastRow = 0
    'lower = Format(TimeValue("08:00 AM"), "hh:mm AMPM")
    'upper = Format(TimeValue("11:00 PM"), "hh:mm AMPM")
    'Debug.Print (lower)
    'Debug.Print (upper)
    
    ' More Code Here
    
    With Processed
       ' .Activate
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
    ' More Code Here
    'LastRow = Main.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    LastRow = Main.Range("n" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ReDim vR(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)
    ReDim vTime(1 To LastRow, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB
   
    Set rngDB = Main.Range("n2", "R" & LastRow)
    vDB = rngDB
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vTime(i, 2) = DayWorkTime(vDB(i, 1), vDB(i, 5))
        vTime(i, 1) = vTime(i, 2) * 24 * 3600
    Next i
        
    With Processed
        .Range("U2").Resize(UBound(vR), 2) = vTime
        .Range("u:u").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        .Range("v:v").NumberFormat = "[H]:mm"
    End With
    

End Sub

Function DayWorkTime(stime, etime)
    Dim Start As Date, EndTime As Date
    Dim vTime()
    Dim i As Long, k As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    
    Application.Volatile (0)
 
    If stime > etime Then
        etime = etime + 1
    End If
    k = Int(etime) - Int(stime)
    
    For i = 0 To k
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vTime(1 To 2, 1 To n)
        If i = 0 Then
            vTime(1, n) = stime - Int(stime)
            vTime(2, n) = 1
        ElseIf k >= 1 Then
            If i = k Then
                vTime(1, n) = 0
                vTime(2, n) = etime - Int(etime)
            Else
                vTime(1, n) = 0
                vTime(2, n) = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
        
    For i = 1 To n
        DayWorkTime = DayWorkTime + DayWork(vTime(1, i), vTime(2, i))
    Next i
End Function
Function DayWork(stime, etime)
    Dim DaySt, DayEt
    Dim Start As Date, EndTime As Date
    
    Application.Volatile (0)
    DaySt = TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
    DayEt = TimeSerial(23, 0, 0)
    With WorksheetFunction
        Start = .Max(stime, DaySt)
        EndTime = .Min(etime, DayEt)
    End With
    If Start > EndTime Then Exit Function
    DayWork = EndTime - Start
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it simply by using excel formulas and is working fine with sample data I populated

[Sample data and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ev9H.png)

Formula used in cell C2

```
=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,"0000000")-2)*15
+IF(TIME(23,0,0)-TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)>=TIME(15,0,0),TIME(15,0,0),IF(TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)<TIME(23,0,0),TIME(23,0,0)-TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0),0))*24
+IF(TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0)-TIME(8,0,0)>=TIME(15,0,0),TIME(15,0,0),IF(TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0)>TIME(8,0,0),TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0)-TIME(8,0,0),0))*24
```

Formula used in cell D2

```
=ROUNDDOWN(C2/15,0)&" Days "&ROUNDDOWN(MOD(C2,15),0)&" Hours "& MOD(C2,1)*60 & " Minutes"
```

What I am trying to do is convert working duration excluding start and finish date by multiplying them with 15hrs. For hours worked in Start date and finish date, i am checking if its in between 08:00 and 23:00 hrs. and the hours worked.

After I get the total I again convert them from total hours to days, hours, and minutes by dividing them by 15 for days, remainder for hours and minutes

Comment: Hello,

As stated in the post, I can already achieve this by the formula I came upon when directly applying the formula in the cells, as well as you provided no alternate solution to using NetworkDays.Intl.

Hope this helps.